# A more efficent way to calculate a boolean column

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a data frame that includes factors with comma separated values. My apologies for not supplying a reproducible example, but my data ends up looking like this:

```
Col_1   Col_2   Col_3

1        0        0
0        0        1
2        0        0
1        2,2      2
3        0        1,2
```

Because I have these comma separated values, I haven't been able to write up a speedy bracketed notation approach that R is awesome at. So I have had to write a for loop to loop through my data frame and change all non-zero entries to a 1.

```
for( i in seq(1:nrow(DF))){
  if(DF$Col_2 ==0){
     DF$NewCol[i] == 0}
   else {
     DF$NewCol[i] == 1}
```

The above works, but takes way too long. Is there a way to speed this up using a different approach in R?

Comment: First, why do you have the seq()?   Second why does the comma issue make a difference, why not use `ifelse` or even brackets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
DF <- read.table(text="Col_1   Col_2   Col_3
1        0        0
0        0        1
2        0        0
1        2,2      2
3        0        1,2", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

DF$NewCol <-ifelse(DF$Col_2 ==0,0,1)
> DF
  Col_1 Col_2 Col_3 NewCol
1     1     0     0      0
2     0     0     1      0
3     2     0     0      0
4     1   2,2     2      1
5     3     0   1,2      0
```

Answer (score 2):

How about simply

```
DF$NewCol <- as.integer(DF$Col_2 != "0")
```

which gives

> ```
>   Col_1 Col_2 Col_3 NewCol
> 1     1     0     0      0
> 2     0     0     1      0
> 3     2     0     0      0
> 4     1   2,2     2      1
> 5     3     0   1,2      0
> ```

and is a lot more efficient than using `ifelse()` to produce a binary result.

Data:

```
DF <- structure(list(Col_1 = c(1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 3L), Col_2 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "2,2"), class = "factor"), Col_3 = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("0", "1", "1,2", "2"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Col_1", 
"Col_2", "Col_3"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```